# Visual Studio's features are unavailable due to internal error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Im currently having issues using the new version of Visual Studio 2022.Im trying to use .Net6 and C# to write some MVC code.
[The Warnings can be shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEgjj.png)

one of the main issues is that it doesnt show the syntax errors and suggestions anymore so its pretty annoying.
the more detail is like this:

```
MessagePack.MessagePackSerializationException : Error writing JSON RPC Message: 

> MessagePackSerializationException: Failed to serialize
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.PinnedSolutionInfo value. --->
> MessagePack.MessagePackSerializationException : Failed to serialize
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.PinnedSolutionInfo value. --->
> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
> 'FormatterCache`1' threw an exception. --->
> System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.    at
> MessagePack.Internal.DynamicObjectTypeBuilder.BuildFormatterToDynamicMethod(Type
> type,Boolean forceStringKey,Boolean contractless,Boolean allowPrivate)
> at
> MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicObjectResolverAllowPrivate.FormatterCache`1..cctor()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Use the "Send Feedback" button in the top right to report problems with Visual Studio. Those reports contain the logs necessary for the developers to diagnose the issue

Comment: It definitely should contain a valid manifest.  The file is not associated with VS2022, it is part of .NET 4.8 and stored in the GAC.  This kind of file corruption is very unhealthy, re-imaging the machine is the wise approach.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and going to the `Visual Studio Installer` and then choosing repair fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try **devenv.exe /ResetSettings** and restart

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Comment: Didn't work.  Just as before after a few minutes of using Visual Studio Community Edition, 17.7.4, errors reappeared at top of screen "Semantic Classification", "Diagnostic Analyzer", etc. currently unavailable.  So I have no syntax checking -- it's like the old days!